# Asp .net core efcore how do I model an entity that has a sequential column which resets based on another sequential column?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a certain entity that has three columns, two of which are sequential.

[image]

How do I go about modelling the entity such that for every distinct `Package` column its corresponding `Group` column would increment when the `Record Number` column reaches a certain maximum value, upon which the `Record Number` column would also be reset.

Below is a representation of how I would like my model to function if the maximum value was 4

[image]

So far, I managed to make the `Record Number` column have an auto-generated sequence by using

```cs
modelbuilder.ForSqlServerHasSequence<int>("Package_seq", schema: "dbo")
    .StartsAt(0).IncrementsBy(1);

modelBuilder.Entity<Package>()
    .Property(o => o.RecordNumber)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Package_seq");
```

but I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: If I had to do it in the DB, I would probably write a stored procedure `dbo.InsertPackage` which `SELECT`ed the last record for the `Package` in question and calculated those numbers accordingly. But I'd just as soon do it in my application layer if I could.

Comment: @Noah, doing this in the application layer may spawn errors because it wouldn't work well when multiple people are inserting data at once, unless there's a way for me to restrict the queries to happen sequentially...

Comment: You might be able to use an [application lock](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176424/does-microsoft-sql-server-offer-an-advisory-locks-feature-like-postgres). But if you go that far, I think you might as well just write the insertion stored procedure instead.

Comment: @Noah alright, thanks for the insight

Comment: You can use transactions to ensure when you read the data that it doesn't change before you write the new record. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions